# Pandas Dataframe row as a formatted JSON output

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame which I am trying to group by customer and print an output ,the to_json is not giving the format. Also I need to create separate json file for each customer, I think using the pandas generic method custom json formatting  is not possible, what should be the direction I should be looking for.

I tried to group by customer_id , first_name and last_name and then set them as index and tried the orientation as index value but that didn't really worked out.

```
import pandas as pd    
data = [{'customer_id': 1, 'first_name':'John', 'last_name':'Doe', 'amount':100, 'sub_amount':50,'total': 150,'product':'tool box'},
        {'customer_id': 1, 'first_name':'John', 'last_name':'Doe', 'amount':50, 'sub_amount':50,'total': 100,'product':'light'},        
        {'customer_id': 2, 'first_name':'Jane', 'last_name':'Doe', 'amount':200, 'sub_amount':50,'total': 250,'product':'iron box'},
        {'customer_id': 2, 'first_name':'Jane', 'last_name':'Doe', 'amount':50, 'sub_amount':50,'total': 100,'product':'led'}    
        ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

customer_id first_name  last_name   amount  sub_amount  total   product
0   1   John    Doe 100 50  150 tool box
1   1   John    Doe 50  50  100 light
2   2   Jane    Doe 200 50  250 iron box
3   2   Jane    Doe 50  50  100 led
```

expected output

```
{
    "frist_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "Product_Details": {
        "too box": {
            "total": 150,
            "amount": 100
        },
        "light": {
            "total": 100,
            "amount": 50
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clients={}
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    clients.setdefault(row['customer_id'], {'first_name': row['first_name'], 
                                            'last_name': row['last_name']})
    clients[row['customer_id']].setdefault('Product_Details',{})[row['product']] = \
              {'total': row['total'], 'amount': row['amount']}

print(json.dumps(clients[1],indent=4))
```